# CakePHP - find function and subsequently multilanguage field

Tags: function, cakephp, find

This is my Model:

```
class Portfolio extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Portfolio';
    public $useTable = 'portfolios';
    public $actsAs = array('Translate' =>  array('title','text1'));
}
```

In my Controller:
....

```
public function index() {
    $this->Portfolio->locale = $this->lang; 
    $this->Portfolio->recursive = 0;
    $Portfolios=$this->Portfolio->find('all');
    $this->set('portfolios', $Portfolios);
}
```

Everything works fine until the moment when I want to add a new multilanguage field .
If I add new field in Model eg. 'text2'

```
class Portfolio extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Portfolio';
    public $useTable = 'portfolios';
    public $actsAs = array('Translate' =>  array('title','text1','text2'));
}
```

find() function in my controller return empty array. WHY??? I must mention that in the database stored dozen records. How to re-display the data no matter what I added additional multilanguage field?

Comment: Pls supply the actual query it's generating and some data in the DB you think it SHOULD be retrieving but isn't.

Comment: This is a problem in CakePHP 2.3 version. In earlier versions this does not happen, for example CakePHP 1.3 everything works ok.